# Sequelize many-to-many still not associated

Tags: sequelize.js

So I am figthing with this for over a week and still getting the same error: `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: roles is not associated to users!`

I would like to have users that can have multiple roles and roles that can have multiple users. The ideas behind the table names are not realy important - I want to learn how to do N:M associations (or associations at all).

My models:
User:

```
export const User = sequelize.define('users', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
  },
  password: Sequelize.STRING,
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
  address: Sequelize.STRING,
  phoneNumber: Sequelize.STRING,
  position: Sequelize.STRING,
  department: Sequelize.STRING,
  createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
  updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
}, {
  tableName: 'users',
  timestamps: true
});
```

Role:

```
export const Role = sequelize.define('roles', {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  roleName: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    unique: true
  }
}, {
  tableName: 'roles',
  timestamps: true
});
```

UserRole:

```
export const UserRole = sequelize.define('users_role', {
  id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  },
  role_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    unique: 'user_role_roleable'
  },
  user_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER
  },
  roleable: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    unique: 'user_role_roleable'
  },
  roleable_id: {
    type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    unique: 'user_role_roleable'
  }
}, {
  tableName: 'users_roles'
});
```

And associations:

```
/*
User.belongsToMany(Role, {
  as: 'u',
  through: 'users_roles',
  constraints: false,
  foreignKey: 'roleable_id'
});

Role.belongsToMany(User, {
  as: 'r',
  through: 'users_roles',
  constraints: false,
  foreignKey: 'role_id'
});*/
User.belongsToMany(Role, {through: UserRole});
Role.belongsToMany(User, {through: UserRole});
```

And I query it like this:

```
User.findAll({ include: [{model: Role}]}).then(r => console.log(r));
```

I tried with and without aliases (need to include it in include), tried other examples from almost identical questions as this one and still end up with that error. What am I missing?

I'm using `"sequelize": "^4.32.2", "sequelize-cli": "^4.0.0"`, express and typescript.

Comment: I just grabbed your code and was able to create a m2m relationship using postgres. Here's a Gist of the code I used (I stripped away some of the extra fields): https://gist.github.com/mcranston18/b41461eb46476116927797609c981252 . Let me know if you can get that working.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit closer to understanding it. I think I must create records from sequelize not manually. After manual inserts I still have the same error, and if I try to add like you did I got `Unhandled rejection TypeError: r.setRoles is not a function`

Do I have to use `.sync()` ? I'd prefer not to.

Comment: You declared the `belongsToMany` with the label `as : 'r'` so you need to use it on the include.

Comment: Here's the gist of what I have now https://gist.github.com/MikeDabrowski/e93b2dd41ab07849ec028425d41adf75. I'm sorry, 'r' was duplicated variable name which could be misleading. I removed all aliases, yet the problem still occurs.

Comment: Your code looks fine but there could be other issues; are you using migrations? have you written them properly? are you using `sync`? are you calling `sync({force: true})`?

Comment: I intend to use migrations, but how is it relevant now, while making proof of concept? By now they are outdated. I am not using sync and not using force.

For now I went with sequelize-typescript, those annotations allowed me to bypass this issue (but sadly created other issues)

Comment: It's relevant because your code looks fine and I'm throwing ideas against the wall :) I have never used sequelize-typescript so I can't speak to that. If you use the code from my gist, you still can't get the association working?

Comment: Ok, I thought you might know something I don't about migrations. Yes, I copied your models 1:1 but with creating I didn't use async/await. I went with promises all the way, you can see it in my code. it is copied directly from my program.